# windows registry of unexpected shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Is there anywhere windows 7 ultimate keeps registry of unexpected shutdowns, for any reasons like: stumble on the power wire or general blackout?
tryed to google it but no luck.

Comment: Windows can’t know specifics if it wasn’t a BSOD.

Comment: Windows will detect an unexpected shutdown, but won't be able to determine the reason unless it was a BSOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Event Viewer under Windows Logs and then System. Any restart rather expected or unexpected will be in there along with a lot of other information regarding services and other issues.